# Unable to kill nodejs process

Tags: linux

Found a nodejs process running in background using this command:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Tried to kill the process using

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | grep '[n]ode' | awk '{print $2}')
```

But it's not killing the process.

Comment: you can try `kill -9` or `sudo pkill -9 node` instead of the whole command

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 node`  it worked!  thanks :)